# Key Result in Group Theory

Tags: group-theory

I've been going about doing one of the key results in Group Theory: Given a
group $G$, for all subgroups $H \leq G,$ $o(H)$ is a multiple of $o(G).$ I have
a feeling a good start to this would be using the properties of $\mod H$ to
start this, because it seems to me that $\mod H$ partitions $G$ into a set
of equivalence classes. However, I'm not sure where to move from here. Do I
need some more lemmas to get to this result? I have this intuition that if I
could biject $H$ with something representing this equivalence class, This proof
may be pretty straightforward.

Comment: You have it backwards: $o(H)$ is a *divisor* of $o(G)$. The bijection you are seeking is $H$ with any (left or right) coset of $H$, that is the map: $h \mapsto ah$ (or $h \mapsto ha$) is bijective for any fixed $a \in G$, as $h$ ranges over $H$.

Comment: The correct key result is [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).

Comment: See also:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267279/proof-of-lagrange-theorem-order-of-a-subgroup-divides-order-of-the-group