# Consequences of Lagrange theorem

Tags: group-theory

Based upon Lagrange theorem, can I state that

- all left cosets in the same group $G$ have the same cardinality?
- the index of a subgroup is the number of elements not included in the subgroup (based on the fact that $xH$ renders $H$ if $x$ is an element of $H$)?

Comment: For the second point, consider $G = \mathbb{Z}_6$ and $H$ the subgroup generated by $2$.  What is the index of $H$ in $G$?

Comment: See also [Proof of Lagrange theorem - Order of a subgroup divides order of the group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267279/proof-of-lagrange-theorem-order-of-a-subgroup-divides-order-of-the-group/4050779#4050779)

Comment: On the first point, each of the left cosets of a **given subgroup** $H\in G$ have the same cardinality as $H$. Different subgroups may have different sizes.

Comment: Cosets have the same cardinality is the cause,  Lagrange theorem is the effect. Not vice versa.

Comment: And cosets are equivalence classes.